# Using jquery selector wildcards to get button click

Tags: jquery, binding, wildcard

I do a post to a PHP file, get back an array of objects and then iterate through them and append the key value pairs in the DOM.  For each row of data, I append an "update" button that I give a unique ID using a counter variable.  THat all works good.  I have a function where I delegate the click of the buttons that were dynamically inserted into the document, I want to bind this click event to any button starting with a phrase.  I keep getting an error in the console:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $("[id^=updateiprange]")

I feel this probably has something to do with all the embedded quotes but I have tried it all sorts of ways......

Here is the loop code that created the DOM output and buttons:

```
$.post(
                    url,
                    {
                     loc_name: locname
                     },
                    function (data) {
                        $("#iprangetable").html("<tr><td></td><td></td><td><p>System ID</p></td><td><p>Loction ID</p></td><td><p>IP Range</p></td><td><p>Subnet</p></td><td><p>VLAN</p></td><td><p>Description</p></td></tr>");
                        $.each(data, function (){
                            ++counter;  //global defined earlier
                            $("#iprangetable").append('<tr>');
                            $("#iprangetable").append('<td><button id="updateiprange'+ counter + ' ">Update</button></td><td><button id="deleteiprange' + counter + '">Delete</button</td>');
                            $.each(this, function (k,v) {
                            if (k == "id") {
                                $("#iprangetable").append('<td><input type="text" id="ipid' + counter + '" value="' + v + '" style="background-color:#ff9900" disabled = "disabled"></td>');
                                }
                            else if (k == "loc_id") {
                                $("#iprangetable").append('<td><input type="text" id="iplocid' + counter + '" value="' + v + '" style="background-color:#ff9900" disabled = "disabled"></td>');
                                 }
                            else if (k == "VLAN") 
                                {
                               $("#iprangetable").append('<td><input type="text" id="vlaninput' + counter + '" value="' + v + '"></td>');
                                }
                            else if (k == "iprange") 
                                {
                                $("#iprangetable").append('<td><input type="text" id="iprangeinput' + counter + '" value="' + v + ' "></td>');
                                }
                                else if (k == "subnetmask") 
                                {
                                $("#iprangetable").append('<td><input type="text" id="subnetinput' + counter + '" value="' + v + '"></td>');
                                }
                                else if (k == "description") 
                                {
                                $("#iprangetable").append('<td><textarea id="ipdescription' + counter + '" rows="5" cols="50">' + v + '</textarea></td>');
                                }
                        });
                            $("#iprangetable").append('</tr>');

                         });
```

And here is the binding for the button:

```
 $(document).on('click', '$("[id^=updateiprange]")', function () {


         });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding statement is incorrect. Change it for this

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[id^="updateiprange"]', function () {...}
```